# Get the Decimal part out of a float number

Tags: objective-c, xcode, floating-point

I need to get the decimal part out of a float number, for example:

float x = 18.30;

I need a way to get the '.30' in another float.. so I will have a float equals to 18.30 and another one equals to .30

Any ideas?

Comment: do you want fmod(18.30, 1.0)?

Comment: Or simply `y1 = (int)x; y2 = x - y1;`,  though it gets ticklish with negative numbers, depending on your intent.

Comment: @gbulmer well, fmodf....

Comment: I just didn't understand the downVote

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a function doing exactly the way you want but you can use this:

```
x - floor(x)
```

Comment: Note that this might be, or not what you expect for x = - 18.3

Answer (score 18):

The accepted answer above (x - floor(x)) works for positive numbers but does not the right thing for negative numbers. Use trunc() instead:

```
x - trunc(x)
```

But the fmod() solution is the one to use if you ask me:

```
fmod(x, 1)
```

Answer (score 9):

The [`modf()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/modf.3.html) function does this more directly than `fmodf()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a family of fmod functions, e.g. fmod(18.30, 1.0), fmodf(18.30, 1.0), etc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    printf("%f\n", fmod(18.30, 1.0));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found using the Objective-C variable types is as following:

```
CGFloat floatingPointNumber = 18.30;
NSInteger integerNumber = floatingPointNumber;
CGFloat floatingPointNumberWithoutTheInteger = floatingPointNumber - integerNumber;
```

Following are the result when executed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Note: use modf or fmod as suggested in other answers.

But don't expect to have exactly the same number as atof("0.30") - as your equals request suggests.

Indeed, it happens that atof("18.30") is the nearest float to atof("18.0") + atof("0.30"), but this operation is not exact, it has a rounding error, as would any sum of atof("0.30") with an integer > 0.

So when you subtract back the integer part, there is no reason to find atof("0.30") back, you only find something near atof("0.30").

Expressed in Squeak/Pharo Smalltalk (double precision used here)

```
(1 to: 100) count: [:i | 0.3 + i = (3/10+i) asFloat].
```

gives

```
-> 100
```

But:

```
(1 to: 100) count: [:i | (3/10+i) asFloat - i = 0.3].
```

gives

```
-> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

x=3.5

y=parseInt(3.5)

fraction_part =( x-y );